# i am getting this error while installing tesseract on centos 6 sudo yum install $HOME/rpmbuild/RPMS/$(uname -m)/tesseract{,-devel}-3.02-*.rpm

Tags: linux, tesseract, rpm

i'm using below command to install tesseract-ocr on cent-os

```
sudo yum install $HOME/rpmbuild/RPMS/$(uname -m)/tesseract{,-devel}-3.02-*.rpm
```

but i'm getting below output :

> No Match for argument: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/tesseract-3.02-*.rpm
>   No package /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/tesseract-3.02-*.rpm available.
>   http://172.21.0.188/HDP-UTILS/repodata/d0bfd914fcb8e2273a3cef67da7471a6f32e6f2edc2789b4cf0bd6fe22c37254-filelists.sqlite.bz2:
>   [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404
>   Not Found" Trying other mirror. No Match for argument:
>   /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/tesseract-devel-3.02-*.rpm No package
>   /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/tesseract-devel-3.02-*.rpm available.
>   Error: Nothing to do

does anyone know how to resolve this and install tesseract successfully.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like two possible issues:

1. There's a hanging `-` at the end of the RPM name. That means the files aren't being seen. If it is a network mounted home directory, `sudo` cannot see them.
2. You have a yum repo set to be at http://172.21.0.188/ but it's not properly responding. *Might* be named `HDP-UTILS` so you can try `sudo yum --disablerepo=HDP-UTILS localinstall ...` once you've resolved the first issue (copy them to `/tmp/`?).